# Is there a duplicate for that? Pokémon GO Edition

Tags: discussion, closing, exact-duplicates, pokemon

Well, with all the trouble people are having with duplication (see my recent meta about dealing with one such dup problem), I figure we should have a nice easy accessable list for people to easily grab a question to dup a new question that has already been asked in regards to the very commonly dup questions for Pokémon GO. There are a number of questions that have a large amounts of duplicates, and these questions are still being asked again, so here is a list of some of the most common dups.

**Note:** please do make sure they are actually dups, don't blindly close stuff, and read both questions.

Comment: Gotta dupe 'em all

Comment: I think we missed a chance for a "Who's that Pokemon" -reference here.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a list of the most commonly repeatedly asked questions. These are almost all related to technical issues that people are having with the game.

[Pokemon Go login issues after update](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278248/pokemon-go-login-issues-after-update)
[Is it possible to log back into a Pokemon Go account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273370/is-it-possible-to-log-back-into-a-pokemon-go-account)
[Does it make a CP difference if you feed candies before or after evolving?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272730/does-it-make-a-cp-difference-if-you-feed-candies-before-or-after-evolving)
[Why are there no Pokémon near me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273564/why-are-there-no-pok%C3%A9mon)
[I can't play Pokemon GO! What's wrong?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274535/i-cant-play-pokemon-go-whats-wrong)
[My Pokemon go account has reset](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278225/my-pokemon-go-account-has-reset)
[Forgot login credentials, can I look up my account from my username?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277034/forgot-login-credentials-can-i-look-up-my-account-from-my-username)
[How do I find an available nickname in Pokémon Go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274243/how-do-i-find-an-available-nickname-in-pok%C3%A9mon-go)
[Why can't I catch Pokemon in Pokemon Go anymore?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274315/why-cant-i-catch-pokemon-in-pokemon-go-anymore)
[Why can't I connect to Pokemon Go via mobile data?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277019/why-cant-i-connect-to-pokemon-go-via-mobile-data)

Comment: how can you sort the most duplicated ones¿?

Comment: [How can I find Pokémon Go's uptime?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272884/how-can-i-find-pok%C3%A9mon-gos-uptime/) might be worth adding

Comment: And [How do I find an available nickname in Pokémon Go?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/274243). Top duplicated questions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-go?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Comment: Another possible one: [How do I select a starter?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274726/how-do-i-select-a-starter). Already [duped from here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276097/pokemon-go-cannot-acquire-starter-pokemon), just flagged it [from here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/280529/pokemom-go-all-starters-not-catchable) too. Btw, wanna make this answer CW? Then anyone can edit to improve the list :)